# What's wrong with my shell code!

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/bash

X="Authenticated Root status: enabled"

SSVCheck=sudo /usr/bin/csrutil authenticated-root status

if [ $SSVCheck != $X ]; then

    echo "<result>Disabled</result>"
else
    echo "<result>Enabled</result>"
fi
```

Comment: With `python-yq` installed on your macOS system (which is what I suppose you're running) from Homebrew, your script can be replaced by `csrutil authenticated-root status | yq -x '{ result: .[] }'`.  Note that `sudo` is not required for running `crsutil` on an unmodified macOS system.

Comment: Apart from the missing command substitution (explained in the duplicate question), you should probably also quote the expansion of `$SSVCheck` and `$X` in the test, as pointed out by ShellCheck if you run your script through it: https://www.shellcheck.net